# what is the best algorithm to traverse a graph with negative nodes and looping nodes

Tags: algorithm, path, routes, shortest

I have a really difficult problem to solve and Im just wondering what what algorithm can be used to find the quickest route.  The undirected  graph consist of positive and negative adjustments, these adjustments effect a bot or thing which navigate the maze.  The problem I have is mazes which contain loops that can be + or -.  An example might help:-

1. node A gives 10 points to the object
2. node B takes 15 from the object
3. node C gives 20 points to the object

route=""

the starting node is A, and the ending node is C

given the graph structure as:-

```
a(+10)-----b(-15)-----c+20

 node() means the node loops to itself   - and + are the adjustments
```

nodes with no loops are c+20,  so node c has a positive adjustment of 20 but has no loops

if the bot or object has 10 points in its resource then the best path would be :-

```
a > b > c    the object would have 25 points when it arrives at c
```

route="a,b,c"

this is quite easy to implement, the next challenge is knowing how to backtrack to a good node, lets assume that at each node you can find out any of its neighbour's nodes and their adjustment level.  here is the next example:-

if the bot started with only 5 points then the best path would be

```
a > a > b > c the bot would have 25 points when arriving at c
```

route="a,a,b,c"

this was a very simple graph, but when you have lots of more nodes it becomes very difficult for the bot to know whether to loop at a good node or go from one good node to another, while keeping track of a possible route.

such a route would be a backtrack queue.

A harder example would result in lots of going back and forth

bot has 10 points

```
a(+10)-----b(-5)-----c-30
```

a > b > a > b > a > b > a > b > a > b > c   having 5 pts left.

another way the bot could do it is:-

a > a > a > b > c

this is a more efficient way, but how the heck you can program this is partly my question.

does anyone know of a good algorithm to solve this, ive already looked into Bellman-fords and Dijkstra but these only give a simple path not a looping one.

could it be recursive in some way or some form of heuristics?

---

referring to your analogy:-

I think I get what you mean, a bit of pseudo would be clearer, so far route()

```
q.add(v)
best=v
hash visited(v,true)

while(q is not empty)
    q.remove(v)
    for each u of v in G

        if u not visited before
            visited(u,true)
            best=u=>v.dist
        else
            best=v=>u.dist
```

Comment: From the example I'm inferring that: "the bot has a resource number, which is an integer, and which cannot be allowed to drop below zero.  Each node has a value; upon visiting the node, the bot's resource changes by that value."  Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a straightforward dynamic programming problem.

Suppose that for a given length of path, for each node, you want to know the best cost ending at that node, and where that route came from.  (The data for that length can be stored in a hash, the route in a linked list.)

Suppose we have this data for n steps.  Then for the n+1st we start with a clean slate, and then take each answer for the n'th, move it one node forward, and if we land on a node we don't have data for, or else that we're better than the best found, then we update the data for that node with our improved score, and add the route (just this node linking back to the previous linked list).

Once we have this for the number of steps you want, find the node with the best existing route, and then you have your score and your route as a linked list.

========

Here is actual code implementing the algorithm:

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, nodes=[]):
        self.nodes = {}
        for node in nodes:
            self.insert(node)

    def insert(self, node):
        self.nodes[ node.name ] = node

    def connect(self, name1, name2):
        node1 = self.nodes[ name1 ]
        node2 = self.nodes[ name2 ]
        node1.neighbors.add(node2)
        node2.neighbors.add(node1)

    def node(self, name):
        return self.nodes[ name ]

class GraphNode:
    def __init__(self, name, score, neighbors=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
        self.neighbors = set(neighbors)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

def find_path (start_node, start_score, end_node):
    prev_solution = {start_node: [start_score + start_node.score, None]}
    room_to_grow = True
    while end_node not in prev_solution:
        if not room_to_grow:
            # No point looping endlessly...
            return None
        room_to_grow = False
        solution = {}
        for node, info in prev_solution.iteritems():
            score, prev_path = info
            for neighbor in node.neighbors:
                new_score = score + neighbor.score
                if neighbor not in prev_solution:
                    room_to_grow = True
                if 0 < new_score and (neighbor not in solution or solution[neighbor][0] < new_score):
                    solution[neighbor] = [new_score, [node, prev_path]]
        prev_solution = solution
    path = prev_solution[end_node][1]
    answer = [end_node]
    while path is not None:
        answer.append(path[0])
        path = path[1]
    answer.reverse()
    return answer
```

And here is a sample of how to use it:

```
graph = Graph([GraphNode('A', 10), GraphNode('B', -5), GraphNode('C', -30)])
graph.connect('A', 'A')
graph.connect('A', 'B')
graph.connect('B', 'B')
graph.connect('B', 'B')
graph.connect('B', 'C')
graph.connect('C', 'C')

print find_path(graph.node('A'), 10, graph.node('C'))
```

Note that I explicitly connected each node to itself.  Depending on your problem you might want to make that automatic.

(Note, there is one possible infinite loop left.  Suppose that the starting node has a score of 0 and there is no way off of it.  In that case we'll loop forever.  It would take work to add a check for this case.)

Comment: I'll add that in the case that there are no positive weight cycles, you terminate after #nodes steps.

Comment: Sorry see in main txt, ive edited to show the psuedo, am I on the right lines?

Comment: There can be negative loops and positive ones, some looping nodes are thrown in to confuse the bot

Comment: @DavidRyan - I'm saying if there is a graph with no positive weight cycles (not that they aren't valid, they don't exist in this graph), there may not be an answer

Comment: yes if there is no positive cycles the bot would have no where to go except a negative node or positive node and simply die if its resource runs out,  but all the maps i have have solutions paths.

Comment: @DavidRyan You were sort of on the right track, but it was easier for me to add running code than try to lead you through it step by step.

Comment: Thank you for submitting an example, the code should be easy to convert to other languages, I will test it on the maps I have, to see if it solves them. Thanks

Comment: Does your solution run because I cant get this working, there seems to be an endless loop causing it to cpu spike.

Comment: @DavidRyan My code works fine on Python 2.6.3.  My first code used to enter an infinite loop if there was no solution in the graph, but I have a fix for all the ones that I know of which I'll update my post with shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your description, it seems like you are just looking for shortest path algorithms. In which case google is your friend.

In the example you've given you have -ve adjustments which should really be +ve costs in the usual parlance of graph traversal. I.e. you want to find a path with the lowest cost so you want more +ve adjustments.

If your graph has loops that are beneficial to traverse (i.e. decrease cost or increase points through adjustments) then the best path is undefined because going through the loop one more time will improve your score.

Comment: i am looking for an efficient way to traverse the graphs above with a cost of >0.  Im sorry maybe using the word "adjustment" makes it unclear, basically each node has a resource level, when a bot moves to that node, the bots resource or life level is either increased or decreased by the weight of the node.  Sorry im not totally versed in the graph terminology. So im looking for an algorithm to decide which path to take.  Btw this is an undirected graph.

Comment: The bots can only have 100 pts so any cost added is invalid past 100, so a node which has 120pts or % only give 100% to the bot.  Maybe points is not the best thing to use.

Comment: Can a bot have <0 pts during the traversal?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some psuedocode

```
steps = []
steps[0] = [None*graph.#nodes]
step = 1
while True:
     steps[step] = [None*graph.#nodes]
     for node in graph:
         for node2 in graph:
             steps[step][node2.index] = max(steps[step-1][node.index]+node2.cost, steps[step][node2.index])

     if steps[step][lastnode] >= 0:
         break;
```

Comment: Thanks for that I will try and program it and see if it works, btw I am working with graphs of 1-23 nodes long, the examples given are extremely simplistic for demonstration.

Comment: Im assuming this the function Max() is an interval function to find the   interval between a and b Max(a,b), what is None*graph.   is this the actual nodes not visited etc..

Comment: It's psuedocode in the style of Python.  None*graph.#numnodes is just an array of length (number of nodes).  Max is just if a>b a else b